# how to calculate PSD of signal with various distance of time in matlab

Tags: matlab, psd

I have a signal x(t) with it's value just like:

```
t = 0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 15, ...
x = 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7,  4,  8, ...
```

as you can see, the problem herre is the time distance between 2 any sample which's not equal. can you tell me how to use matlab to plot it's psd ?
Thank a lot.

Comment: Feels like a homework to demonstrate understanding of FFT's.   Rather than merely call an fft function the student is expected to understand the basic idea that it is a fast way of computing integrals of the product of the data with a sinusoid.   You can evaluate the sinusoid at any point, but the question becomes how to compute the discrete integral.   Define rectangles or trapezoids to represent the volume integrated at each point.  At that point you can probably recognize the similarity to resampling or interpolating the input.   interp1 (some might consider zero fill too.)

Comment: thanks for answer my question. It's not a student homework for understanding fft. I work on my projet and my result is a data file, This is what i see on that file and i have no idea with it.

Comment: If you know nothing about the signal, you can try to interpolate `x` such that it is sampled at a uniform grid. Check out [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) (or type `help interp1` in matlab)

Answer (score 0):

First I would resample the data with interpolation to have a regularly sampled signal. For interpolation algorithm I use spline but you can use also interp1 which would be faster;

```
t2 = t(1):step:t(end); %with this I have a t signal with every sample separated by step
x2 = spline(t, x, t2);
```

Then you can PSD your x2 signal with `fft`, `pwelch`...